# how to rotate an object from a point inside the object

Tags: opengl

Let's say we have a square, and after it is translated to some location, I want to rotate it around a point within the object.

```
     glPushMatrix();
       glTranslatef(50, 50, 0.0);
       glRotatef(joint, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
       glScalef(10,20, 1.0);
       glTranslatef(0.0, -0.5, 0.0);
       glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
       drawSquare(1.0);
     glPopMatrix();
```

The one above only rotates around the (0.0) point after it's scaled. If I change the glRotatef(joint, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) to glRotatef(joint, 0.0, 5.0, 1.0), then the object starts getting twisted.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotations in OpenGL rotate around an axis placed at the origin (0, 0, 0).  In order to rotate around a specific point, you need first to translate that point to the origin, perform your rotation.  In the OP, you would be rotating around the point (-50,-50, 0) (since translations move coordinate systems, and not specific points), and then rotating *joint* degrees around the **Z** axis.

From the OP, assuming that *joint* is updated each frame, I would expect that code to have the square orbiting around the point (-50, -50, 0).

Comment: yes, What you said is correct, but doesnt answer my question exactly. Using the code above, i want to translate the object to (50,50) and then rotate around (50,48)...how should i do that?

Comment: translate it to (0, -2) then and do the rotation